# Como colocar uma imagem de fundo?

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tentando colocar uma imagem de fundo mas não estou conseguindo. alguém pode me ajudar?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}


body, html {
 width: 100%;
}

body {
 background-image: url("img/pizza.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

nav#menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 text-transform: uppercase; 
}

nav#menu li {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #006400;
 padding:0,30%;
 margin: 5%; 
 transition: background-color 1s;
 
}

nav#menu li:hover {
 background-color:#32CD32; 
}

nav#menu a {
 color: #FFD700;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lag="pt-br">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
        
      <title>Pizzaria Santa Tartaruga</title>
  </head>
    <body>
      <header>
              <div id="log"><img src="img/santatmnt.png" height="100" width="100" alt="Pizzari Santa Tartaruga" title="PIZZARIA SANTA TARTARUGA"></div>
              <h1><a href="">Pizzaria Santa Tartaruga</a></h1>
      </header>
    <div id="me">  
      <nav id="menu">
          <ul>
              <li id="ho"><img src="img/raphael.png" height="100" width="100" alt="Raphael" title="RAPHAEL"><a href="">Home</a></li>
              <li id="ca"><img src="img/michelangelo.png" height="100" width="100" alt="Michelangelo" title="MICHELANGELO"><a href="">Cardápio</a></li>
              <li id="po"><img src="img/leonardo.png" height="100" width="100" alt="Leonardo" title="LEONARDO"><a href="">Pedidos Online</a></li>
               <li id="co"><img src="img/donatello.png" height="100" width="100" alt="Donatello" title="DONATELLO"><a href="">Contato</a></li>
          <ul>
    </div>        
      </nav>
      <section>
          <h1> Venha curtir uma aventura ao lado das tarugas mutantes mais amadas do mundo!
              E o que não vai faltar nessa aventura é muita pizza!</h1>
      </section>  
      
      <footer>
             <div> Tel:(21)2243-5243(8hs ás 24hs)</div>
      </footer>
            .
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais específico? Onde deseja colocar a imagem?

Comment: queria colocar a imagem no fundo do body

Comment: Aparentemente, não tem nada de errado em seu CSS. Verifique se o endereço da imagem está correto, e oque acontece sem o background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: Falta fechar a tag do Body, Assim ele você pode definir até onde ele vai.

Answer (score 3):

Inferindo por meio de sua importação  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">`, o arquivo de estilo está na pasta **style**. Contudo, as imagens estão em outra pasta: **img**.

Acontece que o parâmetro **url** na definição de estilo **background-image** procura a imagem com base no diretório no qual está o arquivo CSS.

Se a pasta **img** não é filha da pasta **style** então provavelmente  seja esse o motivo da imagem não estar sendo encontrada, pois a imagem está sendo pesquisada no caminho **style/img/pizza.jpg**.

Se for este o caso, para corrigir, você deve alterar a **url** na definição do estilo para procurar a partir da pasta correta.

Por exemplo, se a pasta **img** é irmã da pasta **style** (ou seja, as duas estão no mesmo diretório) então você pode corrigir indicando que a imagem deve ser buscada primeiramente subindo um nível na estrutura de pastas antes de entrar na pasta **img**, com "../" no início da url.

A solução final ficaria assim:

```
body {  
    background-image: url("../img/pizza.jpg");  
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```