# Imagem de fundo usando bootstrap

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

estou com um problema simples, porém é a primeira vez que me deparo com tal. Usando o bootstrap numa página, não consegui colocar uma imagem de fundo. A página não reconhece o seguinte comando no meu arquivo css:

```
background-image: url(img/ok.jpg);
```

Até consigo mudar a cor usando a seguinte classe no html:
`class="bg-dark, bg-light, bg-danger"`.

Onde estou errando ou o que não aprendi sobre isso? Agradeço se puderem ajudar, pois é trabalho da facul e deve ser entregue. Obrigado.

Comment: Elabore um [MCVE] que replique o erro para podermos analisar o que se passa.

Answer (score 1):

O bootstrap nada mais é que uma biblioteca com várias classes, por isso quando você utiliza `bg-dark`, `bg-light` ou `bg-danger` o seu elemento tem o background alterado. O seu problema não parece ser com a biblioteca em si, mas sim com a vinculação da sua classe css com o seu html.

Cheque o exemplo abaixo, onde é criado a classe `myBackground` que possui a propriedade `background-image` responsável por definir uma imagem de fundo.

Basta passar no seu elemento a classe que você criou e então, o `background` deste elemento será alterado:

```css
.myBackground {
     background-image: url(https://i.imgflip.com/2/34c2k2.jpg);
     color: white
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="myBackground">Essa div deve possuir um background-image com base na minha classe definida no css!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Um dos possíveis motivos no qual seu `background` pode não estar sendo aplicado é que não foi possível encontrar o arquivo que você passou como parâmetro para o `url()`, verifique se o caminho especificado realmente existe e possui a imagem em questão.

Note que esta pergunta já foi respondida diversas vezes e é facilmente encontrada no site, como por exemplo, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152860/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-inserir-uma-imagem-como-background-de-uma-div) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73794/como-colocar-uma-imagem-de-fundo)

Comment: Consegui resolver. O problema realmente era entre o html e a folha de estilo css. Mais especificamente o directório. Muito obrigado. Ajudo muito.